# R: Variable selection for multiple regression w/ percentage dependent variable, serious collinearity

Tags: r, linear-regression, feature-selection

I've got a dataset with 9 continuous independent variables that I'm trying to select between to fit a model to a single percentage (dependent) variable: Score.

Unfortunately, I know there will be serious collinearity between several of the variables.

I've tried using the stepAIC function in R for variable selection, but that method, oddly, seems sensitive to the order in which the variables are listed in the equation...

Here's my R code (b/c it's percentage data, I use a logit transformation for Score):

```
library(MASS)
library(car)

data.tst = read.table("data.txt",header=T)
data.lm = lm(logit(Score) ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4 + Var5 + Var6 + Var7 + Var8 + Var9, data = data.tst)

step = stepAIC(data.lm, direction="both")
summary(step)
```

For some reason, I found that the variables listed at the beginning of the equation end up being selected by the stepAIC function, and the outcome can be manipulated by listing, e.g., Var9 first (following the tilde).

What's a more effective (and less controversial) way of fitting a model here? I'm not actually dead-set on using linear regression: the only thing I want is to be able to understand which of the 9 variables is truly driving the variation in the Score variable. Preferably, this would be some method that takes the strong potential for collinearity in these 9 variables into account.

I know this is a tough question, but I really appreciate you taking the time to look at it...

Best,
Julie

Comment: Julie, this is not offtopic here, but I guess you would get much more sophisticated answers at stats.stackexchange.com, which is a site of exactly the same company as stackoverflow.com. If you want, I can flag your question to be automatically migrated there.

Comment: Hi Thomas -- Thanks very much. I've gone ahead and reposted over at stats.stackexchange.com. Thanks!

Comment: Julie, no, you shouldn't do this, they don't like it... it is better to flag it for migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want Principal Component Analysis (stats::prcomp).

See the document "A Little Book of R For Multivariate Analysis" by Avril Coghlan, section 2.7.  He gives a nice example using downloaded data on various wine producers.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up going with Bayesian Model Averaging (using the `BMS` package in R).